# What is the syntax to write generic child class for React in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the definitions of the class.

```js
export default class Select<T = SelectValue> extends React.Component<SelectProps<T>, {}> {
  static Option: React.ClassicComponentClass<OptionProps>;
  /* more */
}
```

In my code, I can write

```
type CustomType = "foo" | "bar";
export function Page(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Select<CustomType>>
      <Select.Option<CustomType> value="foo">foo</Select.Option>
      <Select<CustomType>.Option value="bar">bar</Select.Option>
    </Select>
  );
}
```

`<Select<CustomType>>` work fines but `<Select.Option<CustomType>>` and `<Select<CustomType>.Option>` does not.

I get

> Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

from the `<Select.Option<CustomType>>`.

> Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

from the `<Select<CustomType>.Option>`.

What is the correct syntax to write the generics?

Comment: It does not matter since it is about the syntax. If you want the full definition, you can look up Select from Ant Design.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, I did not.